# Imprimir filas consecutivas de una misma columna mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql

Intenté imprimir dos filas consecutivas de la misma columna con MySQLi, pero solo imprimo el mismo valor.

```
$result = $link->query("SELECT id_papers, name, pen FROM Papers, Pens WHERE id_papers = id_pen_papers"); // la consulta no es exactamente asi pero es para resumir

foreach ($result as $row) { 
        echo "<option>Page ".$row['id_papers']." & ".$row['id_papers']."</option>";
}
```

Probablemente sea con `mysql_fetch_array` en lugar de foreach, pero no lo logré.

Solución:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($result as $row) { 

  ++$count;
  if($count == 1){ 
      echo "<option>";
  }
  echo $row['id_papers'];
  $count;

  if($count == 1){ 
      echo " & ";
  }

  if ($count == 2){
      echo '</option>';
      $count = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres usar foreach, antes tienes que hacer un fetch de todos los registros y ponerlos en un array:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Por ejemplo, antes del foreach y luego cambiarlo de este modo:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta de esta forma:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option>Page ".$row['id_papers']." & ".$row['id_papers']." </option>";
  }
}else{
  echo = "No hay resultados";
}
```

espero te sirva, me cuentas...

Comment: me devuelve el valor del segundo tanto en el primero como en el segundo.

Comment: no te entiendo bro

Comment: el solo te debe poner las filas que trae la consulta, quizas lo tienes dentro de otro ciclo ?